# access global variable in callback function

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I am trying to modify the cookies global variable inside the 'resource.received' callback function. Unfortunately, it does not work like regular javascript. When I modify cookies in the callback, it is working on a different cookies variable. When I return back to the global scope, cookies remains an empty string.

```
var cookies = "";
casper.on('resource.received', function(resource) {
      for(var i=0;i<resource.headers.length;i++){
          var header = resource.headers[i];
          if(header['name'] == 'Set-Cookie'){
              if(header['value'].length > 0){
                  cookies += " " + header['value'];
              }
          }
      }
})
casper.echo(cookies);
```

How can I access this global variable inside the callback function so I can modify it?

Comment: You should echo the modified "cookies" var in the callback of the 'resource.received' event.

Comment: @JonasSciangulaStreet where do I store the echoed response?

Comment: Do you use an async request? If yes, there's no wait for the callback is ready!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually are modifying the correct variable.

Because casper.on is asynchronous, your casper.echo is running before the completion of your casper.on.

if you try logging or echoing immediately after your for loop in .on, you will see what you are looking for.

Comment: It looks like you are right. I was able to resolve this with using casper.then(function(){...